# Powershell script to bulk import PSTs into mailboxes based on primary smtp address

Tags: exchange, powershell

I have about 30 PST files which I need to import into mailboxes in Exchange 2010.

They are all named by the first part of the email address. For example with johnsmith@domain.com, that PST would be johnsmith.pst. Administrator@domain.com would be administrator.pst etc.

How can I use PowerShell to import these PST files into the relevant mailboxes? They have already been created on the server.

Comment: I can certainly appreciate doing this in a programmatic way based on that criteria, however for only 30 accounts another option may be to create a mapping file that had two columns, the name of the file and the account it should be imported to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by reviewing the techniques mentioned here: 
http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/exchange2010/powershell_import_mailbox.htm

Once you're familiar enough with the techniques, draft a PowerShell script and post it here, we'd be glad to pick it apart and help you understand the process.